# Execute a C program from within another C program as if it was a function call (in Windows)?

Tags: c, function, parameter-passing, return-value

Is it possible call a separate C program (.exe file) within a C program, like if it was a function?

I would like to be able to pass arguments of any kind (like any other function) to this separate program, and get the return value (so it can be used in the host program).

I imagine that the arguments can be passed by using `int argc, char *argv[]`, but I don't know if it's possible to pass integers, arrays, pointers to structures and so on.

On the other hand, I've read that the return value from the main function is system specific. Since I'm using Windows, is there any limitations to this return value (type, size, etc.)? Can it be anything that could be used as a return value in any normal function?

Thanks!

Comment: So there are essentially three things you need to learn here. 1) How to call an external program. 2) How to get the return code of that program. 3) Understanding command line arguments. Take one of them at a time.

Comment: You can exec() another .exe from a C program and pass parameters via argc, argv.  This is not calling another C function though, but calling a whole program.  You could use .dll files and dynamically link them at runtime.  Guess we need to know what you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: This idea of linking dll files at runtime sounds like a better solution to my problem. Thank you for the idea

Comment: I was just wondering if I would be able to treat different C programs like functions. Knowing all the inputs and outputs, you don't have to change them once they're compiled, just "connect" them in a "host" program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe, is the basic premise of the Unix operating system. Unix was designed to allow accomplishing very complex tasks by chaining several commands, piping the (text) output of a command as the input of the next one (this was pretty revolutionary back then).

As **klutt** already suggested, you can accomplish the same with a Windows executable. To his list, I would add learning how to [redirect the input/output of a program to a file handle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output).

The Windows PowerShell extended this concept to allow passing [different data-types](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-datatypes.html) other than text, to some special executables known as `cmdlets`, however, to write your own, you need support from the .Net Framework or the .Net Core infrastructure, so you must do so from a managed language such as C# or C++/CLI.

**Keep in mind that spawning a whole process is an extremely expensive operation (compared to simply calling a linked function), so there is some significant overhead you need to be aware of.**

Comment: Thanks BlueStrat. It seems more complicated than I thought. And as you say, it looks that it is a slow operation since you need to spawn the full processes each time you call them. Maybe it's worth it to investigate this DLL dynamic link at runtime? I'm still not sure.

Comment: You're welcome @Marcos. DLL linking is very flexible indeed. They serve two primary purposes, you can do late-time code binding, that is, you don't actually load code to memory until it is required; and you can implement simple file-swap versioning of your libraries - if you keep the public interface stable between versions. Also you would be able to pass an receive any data type you desire.